# Confirm UIWebView link click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I know that you can detect link clicks in a UIWebView with:

```
UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked
```

and easily access the url, i also know that you can:

```
return YES or return NO
```

if you want to advance to the next page or not...but is there a way to use a UIAlertView to determine if the use wants to return YES or NO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done. When you get the link in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method, save off the URL, display the alert view, then return `NO` from the delegate method.

If the user taps the `YES` button on your alert view, use the saved URL to load a new request in the web view.

Comment: i forgot to mention that the link that will be clicked will be loaded in a iframe thats already in the document within the UIWebView. is it still possible?

Comment: Not sure about that. Perhaps this can be done with some Javascript.